# finding the amount of a word in a list

Tags: python

this is my question:
Return True if the string "cat" and "dog" appear the same number of times
in the given string.
i have tried to use the count method, but it does not work
here is my code:

```
    def catdog(list):
    a = list.count("cat")
    b = list.count("dog")
    if a == b:
        return True
print(catdog(["cat,dog"]))
print(catdog(["cat,cat"]))
```

it outputs true and true, and it is supposed to be true and false. here is the output

Answer (score 0):

That's because the list you're passing has just one string: `"cat,dog"`.

I guess you want that to be two different strings: `["cat", "dog"]`

Also, you could directly `return a == b`. It's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are passing in a list that contains one string with this line:

```
print(catdog(["cat,dog"]))
```

The brackets `[` make it a list, and the quotes `"` make a string inside the list, so it is a list of one item.
You should choose to either pass a list or a string, but not one inside the other.

So either:

```
print(catdog("cat,dog"))
```

Or:

```
print(catdog(["cat", "dog"]))
```

Either method will work, since Python has a `count` method on both `str` and `list` which do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is better:

```
def catdog(x):
    a = x.count('dog')
    b = x.count('cat')
    if a == b:
        return True

pets = ['cat','dog']
print(catdog(pets))
```

You have to use the print function if you have your function return something. Alternatively you could use print within the function:

```
def catdog(x):
    a = x.count('dog')
    b = x.count('cat')
    if a == b:
        print('Cats and dogs are equal.')

pets = ['cat','dog']
catdog(pets)
```